# React Hooks not displaying values correctly

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a simple app concept for my first react native app. Click on a number (1 to 9) and display it (dial in numbers on a phone).

```
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);
const onPress1 = () => setNumbers([...numbers, '1']); // I am saving numbers to a string

<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress1} style={styles.dial1}>
<Text style={styles.number_style}>1</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<Text style={styles.dialed_number_text}> { numbers } </Text> //show the dialed numbers here.
```

Now, when I run the app, the buttons do not react - they are not shown. But when I edit the code in line which displays the numbers, for example I change it to {numbers} and hit save, the numbers are shown.

What is the correct way of printing such array, since I am clearly doing something wrong. Also, what would the best approach that would save me code length when it comes to outputting a phone number that I just clicked on? I can only think of creating 9 onClicks, is there a way to pass a var through click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your styles for the issue of number not showing.
You can can simply pass the number that is clicked from the onPress of touchable opacity like below

```
export default function App() {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);
  
  const onPress = (number) => setNumbers([...numbers, number]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress('1')} style={styles.dial1}>
        <Text style={styles.number_style}>1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress('2')} style={styles.dial1}>
        <Text style={styles.number_style}>2</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress('3')} style={styles.dial1}>
        <Text style={styles.number_style}>3</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Text style={styles.dialed_number_text}> {numbers} </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can tryout the snack below
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/0b9574

Comment: Yes, as you said the problem was in styling. When I removed centering from View element that is encapsulating Text, the problem dissapeared. I had trouble replacing center, so I used marginTop, any idea why is centering creating these problems?

Comment: Can you share the styles? Maybe update the snack and give a url

Comment: I tried reproducing the problem in snack but could not. Gonna just need more experience in styling i guess.

Comment: Generally centering cant be an issue, its hard to give a comment without seeing the code